# Any good approximation for $\Phi^{-1}(1-\Phi(a))$?

Tags: normal-distribution, approximation, gaussian-integral

Let $\Phi$ be the standard Gaussian CDF and $a > 0$.

## Question

Is there any good approximation for $\Phi^{-1}(1-\Phi(a))$ ?

Comment: I don't have any nonobvious suggestions but I am curious what would be considered 'good' here?

Comment: Ya, mine was a really stupid question indeed. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and not just $a > 0$, the exact solution is

$$\Phi^{-1}(1-\Phi(a)) = -a \\
\because 1 - \Phi(a) = \Phi(-a) $$
due to the symmetry with respect to zero. This applies to any symmetric density, or equivalently, any CDF that are rotationally symmetric with respect to $(0,\frac12)$.

Comment: Ya, mine was a really stupid question indeed. Thanks for the input. I was initially interested in approximating $\Phi^{-1}(x)$, which I managed to show to be roughly $\sqrt{2\log(1 / (1-x))}$, BTW.

Comment: I see. Approximating $\Phi^{-1}$ is as respectable a task one can take on as any other. Cheers : )